# Using custom tables in nft

Tags: networking, nftables

I have a Fedora 31 system on which I am using `iptables-nft`. I need this because there is still a bunch of software that expects the legacy `iptables` command line tools.  This means that my nftables configuration has the corresponding set of tables to match the legacy configuration:

```
table ip filter
table ip nat
table ip6 filter
table ip mangle
table ip6 nat
table ip6 mangle
```

I use a containerized VPN service that, prior to nftables, would enable masquerading on my primary ethernet interface by running something like this when the vpn comes up:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.254.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Since upgrading to Fedora 31 and `iptables-nft`, this no longer works. The container (running alpine) does not have the `iptables-nft` compatability wrapper, but it does have the `nft` command itself.

I can't use the `nft` cli to add rules to the existing tables, because this will break `iptables-nft`. But I *can* create new tables. I was hoping I could just apply a configuration like this:

```
table ip vpn {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority filter; policy accept;
        ip saddr 172.16.254.0/24 oifname "eth0" counter masquerade
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        ip saddr 172.16.254.0/24 counter accept
    }
}
```

...but this doesn't appear to have any impact. By setting the chains in this table to priority 0 I was hoping they would match *before* the legacy `nat` table, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some discussions on the `#netfilter` irc channel, it turns out that things are function "as designed". It is **not** possible for one chain to provide *broader* access (in the form of `accept` rules) than that provided by a chain with a `reject` (or `drop`) rule.

An `accept` verdict is only valid in the chain in which it occurrs, and it does not prevent packet processing from continuing in higher priority chains.

In other words, if you have a chain like this:

```
table ip filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
                reject with icmp type host-prohibited
        }
}
```

There is no way to grant access by creating additional chains. The only way to override that `reject` rule is by adding additional rules *in the same chain*.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a guess.

- There is not jump to masquerade in the nft version.
- Do you have to configure the reverse direction?

Comment: There *is* a jump to masquerade in the nft version (that's the rule in the `postrouting` chain: `ip saddr 172.16.254.0/24 oifname "eth0" counter masquerade`)

Comment: From what I have groked you need the word jump, to jump to another chain. E.g. `jump masquerade.`

Comment: That's not valid `nft` syntax. You only use `jump` when sending execution to another chain. E.g., look at the rules generated by `iptables-nft`.

Comment: Sorry I assumed that masquerade was a chain.