# How can I idempotently add an input rule to preconfigured nftables

Tags: nftables

I have a utility that needs a free tcp port. As I don't want to alter existing configuration files I need to be able to dynamically add a rule to nftables.

There is an inet table called filter with input rules:

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        # existing rules
    }
}
```

Adding a rule to it is easy, e.g.:

```
nft add rule inet filter input tcp dport { 4848 } ct state new,established counter accept
```

The problem here is on how to do it in an idempotent way?

- If I run the same command twice, two *identical* rules are generated.
- `nft delete rule inet filter input handle ##` requires a handle number that changes and using `nft -n -a list ruleset | grep ...` to parse the handle number feels wrong
- Adding a new chain with `nft -f` and flush it everytime also does not work because as stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553678/450126):

> *It is **not** possible for one chain to provide broader access (in the form of accept rules) than that provided by a chain with a reject (or drop) rule.*

Comment: If you're always adding the same kind of rule there are ways to solve this without a complex method. If each added rule can be completely different that's an other thing. So could you describe a bit more the use case?

Comment: It is always the same rule that needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to manage it using sets:

```
table inet filter {
    set myport_tcp {
        type inet_service
        elements = { 4848 }
    }   

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        # existing rules
        tcp dport @myport_tcp ct state new,established counter accept
        # more existing rules
    }
}
```

You can empty the set by:

```
nft flush set inet filter myport_tcp
```

And you can add a new port to the set by:

```
nft add element inet filter myport_tcp elements = { 4949 }
```

Or add a multiple ports to the set by:

```
nft add element inet filter myport_tcp elements = { 14949, 9494 }
```